# Pass variable to void function in flutter

Tags: parameters, parameter-passing, flutter, action, void

I want to pass parameter from my dialouge box(Void function) to another void function but getting error

> can't be assigned to the parameter type () void flutter

and setState also not working.

Please check my code here:

**First function**

```
  void _quantity(BuildContext context, productId,quantity){

    setState(() {
      productId = productId;
      quantity = quantity;
      _quantityController.text = '$quantity';
    });
    var alert = new AlertDialog(
     actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: Text("Save"),
          onPressed: _addtoCart(context, productId)
        )
      ],
    );

    showDialog(context: context,builder: (context) => alert);

  }
```

**Second Function:**

```
void _addtoCart(BuildContext context, productId) {
    print("Quantity: $quantity");
    print("productId: $productId");
    print("data: $data");
  }
```

Please check screenshot here

[image]

Comment: What is `box(Void function)` supposed to be? What line causes problems? Do you get an error? Which one?

Comment: If you get an error message please **always** post the full and exact error message, not some approximation.

Comment: This is the error please check screenshot  https://prnt.sc/knty5r

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change

```
onPressed: _addtoCart(context, productId)
```

to

```
onPressed: () => _addtoCart(context, productId)
```

to pass a function, instead of the result of a function call (the return value of `_addtoCart()` which returns `void` and produces the error.

If `_addtoCart` would not take any parameters, you could use the shorter form

```
onPressed: _addtoCart
```

but if you add `()` the function is invoked and the return value passed instead and with `() =>` you can make it a function reference again or in this case a closure.